# how to control window resize, using EventTarget or something else in google closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure

My web application has to automatically resize iframe tag whenever a user changes his browser size. So the net effect is like a google g-mail in which gmail application automatically resize iframe tag containing mail's contents so as to fit itself with browser size.

`window.onresize = function(e){}`   does not work..
becuase I want to dispatch resize function upon loading the page and more use google closure components as possible as I can.

so is there a way to solve my problem out using google closure..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
goog.events.listen(
    window, 
    goog.events.EventType.RESIZE, 
    function (e) { ... }
);
```